# Difficulties setting up emails using AWS SES, Cloudflare and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, email, cloudflare

I have a Wordpress site and am using WP-SES plugin.

In AWS SES I have verified my domain and created rules so that emails under @myDomain.com are routed to an S3 bucket and also a text message is sent.

I've updated the records in Cloudflare yet no emails I send either via the site (using the test function of the plugin or the contact form) or when I send directly via my client are getting through.

Sending a test email via the AWS SES console works.

I fear the issue may be with Cloudflare but I'd very much like some advice.  I've followed a lot of online resources, none of which are working.

thank you!

Comment: are you out of sandbox of ses ?

Comment: my guess you're still in sandbox env, send aws a SES limit increase request to move your SES to production

Comment: and make sure you have bounces and complaints handling in place, else you'll get rejected.

Comment: sandbox has been removed and all restriction on the account (within reason) have been lifted.